# Select/unselect Contact checkbox based on Account Lookup

Tags: selectcheckboxes, accountcontactrelation

There are 3 different checkboxes on the Contact object I have created to indicate 3 different types of Contacts (Primary, Billing, Alternate). I need to create corresponding lookups on the Account object (formula field?) and have the checkboxes check/uncheck based on whether the Account contact lookup matches the correct contact record.

For example, if Jane Smith is the Primary Contact for Acme Company, there needs to be a field on Acme Company that references Primary Contact with a value of Jane Smith. On the Contact record for Jane Smith, the Primary Contact checkbox is checked (value = true). If the Primary Contact lookup on Acme Company is changed to Jill Jones, the checkbox would need to be unchecked on the Contact record for Jane Smith and checked on the Contact record for Jill Jones.

How would I accomplish this?

Comment: Have you considered using Account Contact Roles instead?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this functionality by using Process builder.

As you have 3 different Contact lookup fields on Account, you can have two field update actions:

1. Update the corresponding checkbox field on Contact record (selected in Lookup)
2. Update the earlier Contact record to uncheck the checkbox field, as it is a child of Account using update related records action